# How to add user to Administrators Group

Tags: macos, server.app

I am using OS X Mavericks Server. I want to add a user to the Administrators group but none of the built-in groups show up under Accounts -> Groups on OS X Server.

How can I manage users in the Administrators group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common use of admin with Server.app is to run server.app and administer the server itself.

If that's what you want, use Server.app to tick the administer this server box:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. So clicking the "administer this server" is the only way to manage users in the "Administrators" group?

Comment: I've never tried to automate it since the most I've ever seen ticked is 6 users (actually, my MO is to tick once and delegate to that person if at all possible ;-) I'd start searching in `serveradmin` and krypted.com though if I needed to automate this. It's almost certainly possible just that I haven't ever done the work to figure out how that item is actually stored.